# CryptoKit encrypt file too big for memory

Tags: swift, encryption, apple-cryptokit

Is there a way to encrypt a file that is too big for memory with apples CryptoKit (AES.GCM)?

I have a URL of a big file. That file could be too big for memory so I'd like to encrypt and eventually decrypt the file with AES.GCM using a stream like in this SHA example:

```
var hasher = SHA256()
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4")!
let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path)!stream.open()
let bufferSize = 512
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
             .allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let read = stream.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
    let bufferPointer = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: buffer,
                                               count: read)
    hasher.update(bufferPointer: bufferPointer)
}
let digest = hasher.finalize()
print(digest)
```

Is it currently even possible?

Comment: I don't think so. I only see *incremental* updates for the hash functions. Otherwise it is an extremely sparse cryptographic library / toolkit. There is such a thing as being *too* high level. But then again, I don't think it received any meaningful feedback, [at least not by a review manager](https://forums.swift.org/t/discussion-swift-crypto/33964). Of course, plenty of fanboi remarks below the "design".

Comment: Maarten is right, you could implement your own protocol and write a chunked cipher text with derived keys, but instead I suggest using something like libsodiums stream secret key crypto... @MaartenBodewes, would you agree from an applied crypto perspective?

Comment: Yeah, I can agree with that I suppose.

Comment: Is there any reason I should rather use libsodium [swift implementation of libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium) and not a wrapper of [apples own crypto library](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto)?